# In VS11 Beta, NuGet console default to project folder

Tags: console, nuget

I've just installed VS11 beta, oddly in NuGet console it defaults to the project folder. 
i.e.

**PS D:\Projects\HelloWorld\trunk>** 
How do I make it go back to **PS>** ?? So it can run all the nuget commands?

Much Appreciated!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is a [bug in NuGet](http://nuget.codeplex.com/workitem/1953). The only work-around we know currently is to restart Visual Studio. We plan to fix this in the upcoming 1.8 release.

Comment: Thanks for letting us know! The VS11 EF generator has some glitches too. good thing is I can switch freely between VS2010 and 11!